# Javascript philosophy and events

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm currently learning NodeJS and Javascript OOP. I need to use a package which uses events handler. But I'm a bit confused with the Javascript philosophy.

I've got a node module which runs like this :

```
var Module = require("...");
//...
MyObject.prototype.start = function() {
    var myModule = Module();

    myModule.on('connected', function(device) {
        console.log('New device connected !');

        device.on('status', function(status){
            console.log('Device status : '+status);

            device.transfer("someStuff");
        });
    });
}
//...
```

I would like to call the "transfer()" method of "device" object outside of the "device.on()" events handler.
Are there any possibilities ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT : I'm trying this

```
var Module = require("...");

MyObject.prototype.start = function() {
    var myModule = Module();

    myModule.on('connected', function(device) {
        console.log('New device connected !');

        device.on('status', function(status){
            console.log('Device status : '+status);

            //device.transfer("someStuff");
        });
    });
}

MyObject.prototype.transferData = function(){
    device.transfer("someStuff");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just call it outside the `device.on` handler.

Comment: You can call that function whenever you want.  What don't you understand?

Comment: Yeah but I can't add a method to MyObject which calls device.transfer() ?

Comment: @nOwXO You can only use `device` inside of your `myModule.on('connected', ...)` callback, since `device` is supplied as an argument to that callback. You must define any method that uses `device` inside that callback. It might be helpful to **show some non-working code** to more clearly demonstrate what you're doing that isn't working.

Comment: I edited my question with non-working code

Comment: @nOwXO Great, thanks! That code is very helpful. Your question should probably read "outside of the `myModule.on` events handler" instead of  "outside of the `device.on()` events handler"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are multiple methods of `MyObject` that want to access `device`, there are a couple of ways you can design this:

- When `MyObject` is instantiated, it promisifies the `on('connected')` callback and stores it as, let's say, `devicePromise`. All methods on the prototype follow this pattern: `return this.devicePromise.then(function (device) { /* do whatever */ })`. Any methods that returned values now return promises
- `MyObject` cannot be directly instantiated, but can only be created via a factory function that returns a promise of a `MyObject` instance. This factory function calls `on('connected')`, and resolves the returned promise with a `MyObject` instance in which the `device` property is set. All methods can access `this.device`

Comment: Thank you ! I tried your solution but my events handler are not listening anymore.
I've got in my constructor :
`this.devicePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    myModule.on('connected', function(device) {
   console.log(device.name);
  });
 });`
And in my methods :
`return this.devicePromise.then(function(device){
  device.on('status', function(status) {
   console.log(status);
  });
 });`
But it doesn't works

Comment: @nOwXO So you're close, but what you're missing is that you need to have `myModule.on('connected', function(device) { ...; resolve(device); })`. Note that the important part is `resolve(device)`, otherwise the promise is never satisified.